# Error logging in React ES6

Tags: reactjs, logging, yarnpkg, es6-modules

I am running a react app (ES6). I am trying to find modules that will allow me to print error messages to my terminal console. All the modules I found simply printed the messages to the browser console.

Comment: Well, since you react app is client-side, you logs will be client side. Is there a specific reason why you would want your logs to  email printed in your terminal? If it is for collecting errors you can make use of a large amount of tools that will allow you to gather and review them.

Comment: It seems easier to view errors dynamically right now through the terminal window. Eventually however when I get other to use this, I would like to errors to be stored to a file. What do you recommend for that?

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see. Well when you want to do this and log them in a file you are better of using something like sentry (https://github.com/getsentry). Pretty sure that you can also stream the logs to you back-end!